# Creating html file in C error

Tags: html, c, shapes

So essentially I have a few of these codes and my job is to create a html file using C. and I constantly have a problem with calling the function in the main.

error message was "Too few arguments to function "rect3"

```
void rect3(FILE* ofp, int x, int y, int width, int height, int strokewidth, int r, int g, int b, float opacity)
{
    fprintf(ofp, "\t\t\t<rect x=\"%d\" y=\"%d\" width=\"%d\" height=\"%d\" style=\"fill:none; stroke-width:%d; stroke:rgb(%d,%d,%d); stroke-opacity:%f;\"/>\n",
            x, y, width, height, strokewidth, r, g, b, opacity);
}
```

and in the main I have essentially this

```
int strokewidth;
strokewidth = 8;
x = 0;
y = 0;
width = 800;
height = 600;
r = 255;
g = 51;
b = 153;
opacity = 1.0;
rect3(x, y, width, height, strokewidth, r, g, b, opacity); //<< Error msg comes up in this line
```

Comment: The function expects 10 arguments, you're calling it with 9 arguments. Isn't the error message clear about that?

Comment: You're missing the first argument, `FILE *ofp`.

Comment: oh my god... completely forgot that was an argument, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass a FILE * as the first argument to rect3().

You'll have to open the file (since it's being written to without making sure that it's open) so that the output can be written to it. You would also have to close it when you're done with it.

Comment: oh right, forgot about the FILE* as an argument. thanks

Answer (score 0):

parameters not match.
FILE* ofp, you forget this parameter